# PHP/MySQL: How to compare the sum of certain fields on a query to a number?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of users that can enroll into courses and pay for them.

**And I want to do a list of those users, and the courses that they are enrolled in and show there how much they've paid for each course already.**

### These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    userID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userEmail char(50) null,
    userDNI int(10) null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE rolesUsuarios (
    rolesUsuariosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    nombreRol char(50) not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE cursos (
    cursoID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombreCurso char(100) not null,
    cursoPrecio int(10) null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE cursosUsuarios (
    cursosUsuariosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    cursoID int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE pagos (
    pagoID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    pagoMonto int null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE pagosVerificados (
    pagosVerificadosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    pagoID int not null,
    cursoID int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### And this is the query that I'm using:

```
SELECT usuarios.userID AS useridd, usuarios.userEmail, usuarios.userApellido, rolesUsuarios.userID, rolesUsuarios.nombreRol,
                  cursos.cursoID, cursos.nombreCurso,
                  cursosUsuarios.cursoID, cursosUsuarios.userID,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rolesUsuarios.nombreRol SEPARATOR '||') AS 'roles',
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cursos.cursoID,' - ',cursos.nombreCurso SEPARATOR '||') AS 'cursos',
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT '$ ',pagos.pagoMonto,' course ID ',pagosVerificados.cursoID,'payment ID',pagos.pagoID ORDER BY pagos.pagoID SEPARATOR '||') AS 'pagos'

                FROM usuarios   LEFT JOIN rolesUsuarios ON usuarios.userID = rolesUsuarios.userID
                                LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios ON usuarios.userID = cursosUsuarios.userID
                                LEFT JOIN cursos ON cursosUsuarios.cursoID = cursos.cursoID
                                LEFT JOIN roles ON rolesUsuarios.nombreRol = roles.nombreRol
                LEFT JOIN pagosVerificados
                ON rolesUsuarios.userID = pagosVerificados.userID
                LEFT JOIN pagos
                ON pagosVerificados.userID = pagos.userID
                AND pagosVerificados.pagoID = pagos.pagoID

                GROUP BY useridd
```

This is the result I get: A list of all payments in the same list, and I want to separate them according to each course.

[image: Issue]

**The ultimate goal is to be able to compare the price of each course with the sum of all payments done for each course and know if there's any debt in any course.**

How may I do that? Could I do that using PHP directly and that query, or should I modify the query?

Comment: `sum(cost_of_class) - sum(payments_made)`

Comment: Yes, but that would sum up all payments, even if they are from different classes

Comment: you should use HAVING beside of SUM. Try a simple search for HAVING

Comment: Use sum as @MarcB suggested but first group by the class. That way each sum is scoped to a single class.

Comment: How may I sum only the field with the payments concatenated? like `SUM(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pagos.pagoMonto))`. Because if I do just `SUM(pagos.pagoMonto)` the sum is incorrect (it gets sum up three times). And if I do `SUM(DISTINCT pagos.pagoMonto)`, it won't sum all fields.

Answer (score 0):

Again I don't speak whatever language this is, but I would start with this and this join to others tables as needed.

```
select A.userID, A.cursoID, B.cursoPrecio, IFNULL(sums.totalpaid, 0) `totalpaid`, (B.cursoPrecio - IFNULL(sums.totalpaid, 0)) `amount left`
from `cursosusuarios` A 
inner join `cursos` B on (A.cursoID = B.cursoID)
left outer join (
select A.userID, A.cursoID, sum(B.pagoMonto) `totalpaid`
FROM `pagosverificados` A 
inner join `pagos` B on (A.userID = B.userID and A.pagoID = B.pagoID)
group by A.userID, A.cursoID ) sums on (A.userID = sums.userID AND A.cursoID = sums.cursoID)
```